# Use curl to upload files to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, curl

I am trying to upload an image to a SharePoint Online Document Library using curl.

This is the command I use:

```
curl --ntlm --user user@domain.com:password --upload-file test.docx https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/leansite/TestDoc/test.docx -verbose
```

Where the Document Library is TestDoc.

I am getting 401 Unauthorized exception. I think maybe -ntlm is not liked by SP Online.

Is Claims-Based Auth supported in curl? I think this maybe the cause.

```
*   Trying ip...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to contoso.sharepoint.com (ip) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Contoso\PAL\curl-7.52.1-win32-mingw\curl-7.52.1-win32-mingw\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=WA; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; OU=Microsoft Corporation; CN=*.sharepoint.com
*  start date: Feb 23 19:42:10 2016 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 22 19:42:10 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "contoso.sharepoint.com" matched cert's "*.sharepoint.com"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; OU=Microsoft IT; CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using NTLM with user 'user@domain.com'
> PUT /sites/Maynilad/leansite/TestDoc/test.docx HTTP/1.1
> Host: contoso.sharepoint.com
> Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKADk4AAAADw==
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> Referer: rbose
> Content-Length: 0
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAADAAMADgAAAAFgomihBuCtJg24sMAAAAAAAAAAPIA8gBEAAAABgOAJQAAAA9ZAEwATwAwADAAMQACAAwAWQBMAE8AMAAwADEAAQAeAFUAUwBSADEANQA3ADEANQA4ADEANQAtADIANgA0AAQALABZAEwATwAwADAAMQAuAE0AUwBPAFAAUgBEAC4ATQBTAEYAVAAuAE4ARQBUAAMATABVAFMAUgAxADUANwAxADUAOAAxADUALQAyADYANAAuAFkATABPADAAMAAxAC4ATQBTAE8AUABSAEQALgBNAFMARgBUAC4ATgBFAFQABQAsAFkATABPADAAMAAxAC4ATQBTAE8AUABSAEQALgBNAFMARgBUAC4ATgBFAFQABwAIAKGzFCrTcNIBAAAAAA==
< SPRequestGuid: 32f2cb9d-d031-3000-bd41-8829cb9968bc
< request-id: 32f2cb9d-d031-3000-bd41-8829cb9968bc
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< SPRequestDuration: 4
< SPIisLatency: 2
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.6105
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
< P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
< Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2017 15:05:38 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host contoso.sharepoint.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Maynilad/leansite/TestDoc/test.docx'
* Found bundle for host contoso.sharepoint.com: 0x33d88c8 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host contoso.sharepoint.com
* Connected to contoso.sharepoint.com (ip) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using NTLM with user 'user@domain.com'
> PUT /sites/mysite/leansite/TestDoc/test.docx HTTP/1.1
> Host: contoso.sharepoint.com
> Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAJwAAAB6AXoBtAAAAAAAAABYAAAAMgAyAFgAAAASABIAigAAAAAAAAAuAgAABYKIogoAOTgAAAAPCXakIO68kku98ZzxgDsBa0wAZQBhAG4AQABjAGwAaQBuAGsAaQB0AHMAbwBsAHUAdABpAG8AbgBzAC4AYwBvAG0ATABFAEEATgAtAEQARQBMAEwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPkUT7d53BAivjcEqnWQnMQEBAAAAAAAAobMUKtNw0gFseLkaGI+DNAAAAAACAAwAWQBMAE8AMAAwADEAAQAeAFUAUwBSADEANQA3ADEANQA4ADEANQAtADIANgA0AAQALABZAEwATwAwADAAMQAuAE0AUwBPAFAAUgBEAC4ATQBTAEYAVAAuAE4ARQBUAAMATABVAFMAUgAxADUANwAxADUAOAAxADUALQAyADYANAAuAFkATABPADAAMAAxAC4ATQBTAE8AUABSAEQALgBNAFMARgBUAC4ATgBFAFQABQAsAFkATABPADAAMAAxAC4ATQBTAE8AUABSAEQALgBNAFMARgBUAC4ATgBFAFQABwAIAKGzFCrTcNIBBgAEAAIAAAAIADAAMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAAK18CI9jD04glSs15ZOtvhr5xAix32o2pTP80JxFY/pyCgAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> Referer: rbose
> Content-Length: 11272
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< SPRequestGuid: 32f2cb9d-5046-3000-bd41-8e88997aa3bc
< request-id: 32f2cb9d-5046-3000-bd41-8e88997aa3bc
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< SPRequestDuration: 7
< SPIisLatency: 1
* NTLM handshake rejected
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.6105
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
< P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
< Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2017 15:05:38 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Comment: If you are not bound to curl and can run Node; use Gulp SPSync by Wictor Wilen : http://www.wictorwilen.se/announcing-gulp-spsync-a-gulp-plugin-that-syncs-local-files-with-a-sharepoint-site

Comment: I am facing similar issue. How did you change the CURL command to upload files to SharePoint online. I didn't understand the phpSPO library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, `NTLM` is not supported for SharePoint Online. Instead you could consider either [Claims-Based Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx) (SAML) or [OAuth flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687470.aspx).

For implementation details you could refer to [phpSPO library](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) (which in turn utilizes [cURL library](http://no.php.net/curl)), in particular:

- [`SamlTokenProvider.php`](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/blob/master/src/Runtime/Auth/SamlTokenProvider.php) - for Claims-based identity
- [`ACSTokenProvider.php`](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/blob/master/src/Runtime/Auth/ACSTokenProvider.php) - for OAuth flow

> Disclaimer: I'am an original author of this library

Comment: Thanks for this, looks intuitive and better suited for Sharepoint. Is this available for scripting (ex. run on a daily basis?)?

Comment: I am currently trying it out but am encountering difficulties. I am receiving Uncaught Error: Class 'AuthenticationContext' not found in test.php. But I have defined require_once on the top of my php script. <?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

 ?>

Comment: I have included necessary use now. It says File Uploaded successfully , but when I look at the DocLibrary, it isn't there. There is no error message also.

Comment: @Water, for a script based solution, would it be an option to consider to switch to PowerShell, like explained in [this post](https://blog.vgrem.com/2014/07/29/uploading-files-into-office-365-via-powershell/)

Comment: We are doing it in Linux so I think Powershell is out as an option. I have made it working using the UploadFiles sample you have. The SaveFile function doesn't work though; is it supposed to have a different purpose?

Comment: @Water, under `examples` section, there is a [file_examples.php](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/blob/master/examples/SharePoint/file_examples.php#L81) which contains `uploadFiles` function intended for uploading a files, could you please give it a try?

Comment: Yes Vadim, I have tried it and it worked. Thanks! I am just wondering, the earlier code you gave me is the saveFile method. What is the difference between the 2? After this, I will mark you as answer :)

Comment: Water, that's right `SaveFile`  utilizes [SaveBinary function](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/blob/969242424b7c6b1c4be1062afbf2996215e3f505/src/SharePoint/File.php#L154)  which is supposed to be used for updating the existing file only. For adding a new file `FileCollection.add` method should be used.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
curl --ntlm --user username:password --upload-file test.docx https://<sharePoint_folder_url>/test.docx -verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

In URL, specify a link from "copy link" at the webGUI.

```
curl --ntlm --user user@domain.com:password --upload-file test.docx "link_from_guid"
```